# Year in DD/MON/YY converts to 1943 and 2043 in 2 different tables with the same data

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying the same SQL on 2 different tables in the same database.

```
SELECT date_of_birth_1 from Table1 where id = '1111';
```

**The output is 31/DEC/43.**

```
SELECT date_of_birth_2 from Table2 where id = '1111';
```

**The output is 31/DEC/43 again.**

But when I run

```
SELECT extract(year from date_of_birth_1) from Table1 where id = '1111';
```

**The output is 1943.**

And when I run

```
SELECT extract(year from date_of_birth_2) from Table2 where id = '1111';
```

**The output is 2043.**

I don't understand what is going on, could you please help me. I want both the tables to use the same reference year which is 1900.

**Edit: This happens only for some dates.**

```
select EXTRACT(year FROM TO_DATE('01/AUG/43')) from dual;
```

The output is 2043.

```
select EXTRACT(year FROM TO_DATE('04/MAR/53')) from dual;
```

The output is 1953.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Oracle is only showing the last two digits of the year.  In one table, the date would seem to be 1943-12-31 and in the other 2043-12-31.

You can see the full date using `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(dob, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

If you need to fix the data, you can do something like:

```
update t
    set dob = add_months(dob, -12 * 100)
    where dob > <whatever threshold you want here>
```

Comment: This happens only for some dates. I have edited the question.  '01/AUG/43' gives the year as 2043 but '04/MAR/53' gives the year as 1953. :(

Comment: @learner . . . That is why there is a `where` clause, so you can update the *future* dates.  The values are stored in the database as valid dates, probably between 1900 and 2000, although some of the dates might indeed be between the years 0 and 100.

Comment: I need help in understanding why "to_date" function gives different values for year.  I want to be able to fix the source of the problem.

Comment: @learner . . . The source of the problem is that the data was inserted incorrectly (probably with 2-digit years).  The fix is something like the `update` I included in the answer.